# Issue with supressing details if a date field is null

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I am working on a report and i need to supress the details section if a date field is null. 
I have tried to use the section expert and formula

Isnull({GiftsReport.Date1})=true

I need to supress details section if {GiftsReport.Date1} field is blank or null. But it does not supress it. GiftsReport is a view I am not sure if that makes any kind of difference.

If I use the same formula in selection formula for the report. It suppresses the whole report.

Please if anyone can help me with this I will reallyy appreciate it.

Thanks,

Parvesh Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text for the `details` section's conditional-suppression formula should be:

```
Isnull({GiftsReport.Date1})
```

** edit **

```
// {@null_test}
If Isnull({GiftsReport.Date1}) Then "NULL"
Else "NOT NULL"
```

Comment: I changed it to Isnull({GiftsReport.Date1}) but the report is still not supressing details section.

Comment: Are you certain that this field is actually returning a `null` value?

Comment: You could straight away put your edited formula as the Supression formula. You dont need {@null_test} formula. 

You could also put the {Date1} field somewhere on the report to see what value it returns.

Comment: Hello Craig its working fine now. I made a mistake at the null test formula.   Thankss a lott